# How To Show Invalid Email Message with Validator in React

Tags: reactjs, validation

I'm doing a React App and have installed `npm install validator` for email validation, so everything works just fine (data won't send to the database if email is invalid), but I don't know how to show a message when the user input an invalid email. Thank you all!

Here's my Email schema:

```
const validator = require('validator');

const EmailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: 'Email is invalid',
            isAsync: false
        }
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
});

const Email = mongoose.model("Email", EmailSchema);
module.exports = Email;
```

Here's my form:

```
<form className="feedback" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
    <h5>Leave us a feedback</h5>
    <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={(event) => {
                setEmail(event.target.value);
            }}
            required
            className="input-email"
        />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Message:</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your message here:..."
            onChange={(event) => {
                setMessage(event.target.value);
            }}
            required
            className="input-food"
        />
    </div>
    <button className="email-btn">Send Email</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const validator = require('validator');

const EmailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: [ validator.isEmail, 'invalid email' ]
    },
    message: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
});

const Email = mongoose.model("Email", EmailSchema);
module.exports = Email;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.